# How to avoid widgets added to sidebar on theme activation?

Tags: widgets, sidebar, register-sidebar

I am registering 3 sidebars on `widgets_init`

```
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' =>  esc_html__('Left Sidebar','creatus'),
        'id' => 'left',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<div class="widget_title_holder"><h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3></div>',
    )); 

   // right sidebar
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => esc_html__('Right Sidebar','creatus'),
        'id' => 'right',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<div class="widget_title_holder"><h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3></div>',
    ));

    // lateral header sidebar
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => esc_html__('Lateral header sidebar','creatus'),
        'id' => 'lateral-header-sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<div class="widget_title_holder"><h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3></div>',
    ));
```

When I activate the theme for the first time on a clean WP install 6 widgets get automatically added to `lateral-header-sidebar`

http://prntscr.com/l9cx84

Am I registering them the wrong way or why are they added to this particular sidebar and not any other?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your registration code looks fine to me. How's the rest of your theme code? Are there any other widget related functions that might hook into `after_switch_theme` for example? Something along these lines, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757461/how-to-populate-widgets-on-sidebar-on-theme-activation Or are there any plugins that might be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Widgets are stored in the `wp_options` table ( assuming the database prefix is `wp_` ). You can retrieve the option, and remove the widgets manually:

```
// Get all the associated widgets
$sidebar_widgets = get_option ( 'sidebars_widgets' );

// Check this specific sidebar
if ( isset( $sidebar_widgets [ 'lateral-header-sidebar' ] ) ) {
    unset ( $sidebar_widgets [ 'lateral-header-sidebar' ] );
    // Update the option
    update_option ( 'sidebars_widgets', $sidebar_widgets ); 
}
```

You can do this in your theme activation hook.

Comment: thnx for that but it does not explain the actual issue. Why are they added in the first place? Cleaning up on theme install is not what we should be doing.